# Multiply mean values

Tags: summation, means

I was wondering if its allowed to multiply two mean values. I thought of the following:
$$y = x_1 * x_2$$
They values $x_1$ and $x_2$ are from different sample sets and are not related. They only have to same number of samples in them. 
I think its wrong to calculate $\bar{y}$ like this:
$$\bar{y}=\bar{x_1}*\bar{x_2} $$
Because:
$$
\bar{y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum x_{1i} * \frac{1}{n}\sum x_{2i} = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum x_{1i}x_{2i}
$$
Am I right ?

or does it resolve to this and it is allowed?
$$
\bar{y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum x_{1i} * \frac{1}{n}\sum x_{2i} = \frac{1}{n}\sum x_{1i}x_{2i}
$$

Comment: You're missing a ***LOT*** of context here. Are these two sample averages of the same set? Or perhaps are there two sets of data, $x_{1,i}$ and $x_{2,i}$, with respective averages $\mu_1,\mu_2$, and you want to find the average of everything altogether (i.e. all of the $x_{j,i}$ at once, preferably in terms of the $\mu_j$)? Are you trying to find the average of their products? I'm really unsure what you're doing.

Comment: Two different sample sets they only got the same number of samples.

Comment: Can't tell if this will help you, but I observe that $\frac{2+4}{2} \times \frac{5+7}{2} = 3 \times 6 = 18 \not= 19 = \frac{10+28}{2} = \frac{2 \times 5 + 4 \times 7}{2}$.

Comment: Yeah that helps and I tried that already, but I dont quite understand how I need to resolve my function above? Why do I get $n^2$ ?

Comment: Oh okay. I thought that was possible because of the same number of samples inside the set. Thanks! If you want you can write the answer.

Comment: Perhaps multiplying $x_1$ and $x_2$ to produce an aggregate statistic is an uninformed attempt at a [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean?wprov=sfla1)? But I'm having trouble imagining a context in which that would be appropriate with sample averages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum x_{1i} \times \sum x_{2i} \neq \sum x_{1i}x_{2i}$$

As a simple example, consider

$$(1 + 2 + 3) \times (4 + 5 + 6) \neq 1\cdot4 + 2\cdot 5 + 3 \cdot 6$$

Answer (score 2):

two sums do not multiply like you did it. Look up Cauchy product,
$(x_1+x_2)*(y_1+y_2)\ne x_1y_1+x_2y_2$

Comment: Strictly speaking, OP is relying on $(x_1+x_2) \times (y_1+y_2) = \mathbf{2}(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)$. If that is true, then the product of the means equals the mean of the products. (Divide both sides of that equation by $4$ to see this.)